# How to enable Namespace in Centos 6.5

Tags: linux, centos

I followed the steps mentioned at https://spredzy.wordpress.com/2013/11/22/enable-network-namespaces-in-centos-6-4/. But it doesn't seem to help. I'm still getting this error -

`[root@localhost app]# ip netns
 Object "netns" is unknown, try "ip help".`

Can anyone help me in enabling Linux Namespaces in Centos 6.5?

Comment: did you actually install the mentioned kernel from RDO repo ?

Comment: @tonioc: Problem's solved. In CentOS 6.5 - kernel itself supports network namespace, but iproute does not support network namespace. I had the OpenStack kernel but wasn't using the correct iproute rpm which is -

`iproute-2.6.32-130.el6ost.netns.2.x86_64`

Installing this rpm solved it.